# Request body is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I use Express.js to make api.

The issue I am facing is access to body of request.

I can access to body when api is on server.js.

```
// backend/server.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/hello", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

[postman post request to "/hello"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFdWE.png)

[successfully working api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR32m.png)

So this works fine. That's good. However, it does not work in this case.

```
// backend/server.js
app.use(require("./routes"));


// backend/routes/index.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/api", require("./api"));

module.exports = router;


// backend/routes/api/index.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/users", require("./users"));

module.exports = router;


// backend/routers/api/users.js
const router = require("express").Router();
router.post("/", auth.optional, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

[failed postman post request to "/api/users"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5GV8.png)

[failed api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6C6r.png)

As you see, this api/users api runs fine, but I cannot access to body of request :(

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you import the `body-parser` with this line:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

And then you enable it:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Both is required so that `req.body` exists, and contains what you expect – a parsed JSON object, taken from the request stream.

In your second example, both lines are missing, and hence `req.body` is `undefined`. You need to add them to your sample, then it will work.

Please note that `req.body` is not provided by Express itself, but is an extension provided by the `body-parser` middleware, hence you have to install it, import it, and actually `use` it.

For an example of how to use `body-parser`, see its documentation, either the section [Express/Connect top-level generic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic) or the section [Express route-specific](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#express-route-specific).

Comment: Thank you very much ! I needed to add router.use(bodyParse.json()) to access body! I select your answer as this official answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with body-parser or multer middleware may hope it will help you

```
  npm install body-parser --save
```

and then do this in your code

```
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 var app = express()
```

parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

parse application/json

```
   app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Or

If your body parser does not work then try with multer middleware it will work

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer()

app.post('/profile', upload.none(), function (req, res, next) {
    // req.body contains the text fields
})
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention bodyparse in my post. actually, actually, I installed body-parser in my backend package.json.

Comment: ok, I updated...because i have same issue but when i try multer middleware it work for me

Comment: You dont just need to install it to package.json but this line `app.use(bodyParser.json())` is very important!